# How can modify WSGIRequest in django REST framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, dictionary, wsgi

i have a request param as:

<WSGIRequest: GET 'dashboard/auth/complete/activities-update/?session_key=abbccddeeff&state=GKW9z7ET
AR&response_type=code&scope=update&show_login=true'>

I want to remove the session_key from the request.SO I tried the following code:

```
request.GET._mutable = True  # to make it editable
request.GET.pop("session_key")
request.GET._mutable = False
```

but request is still same
how ever request.GET is getting updated but request remains to be the same.
I need request as:

<WSGIRequest: GET 'dashboard/auth/complete/activities-update/?state=GKW9z7ET
AR&response_type=code&scope=update&show_login=true'>

Comment: tried this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9781233/16250404

Comment: Should I try doing this? I am not storing anything in the session.

Comment: Moreover, del form session will give KeyError: 'session_key'